# Looking in rows of a excel table with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, lxml

i have in Python a programm that loops in an excel sheet to get all the values from a column1 (using pandas). It loops so i can put the value as an xml file (with lxml) :

```
raw_data = pd.read_excel('myfile.xls', sheet_name='name')
for row in raw_data.iterrows():
    column_values = et.SubElement(root, 'values')

    value = et.SubElement(column_values, 'value')
    value.text = str(row[1]['Column1']
```

The problem i am having is that it loops until the last row with values. So if i have Column1 with 6 rows of data but on the same sheet i have an other column with 10 rows, it will loop 4 rows more. How can i prevent that and only make sure it loops for all the values in my column ?

thank you

**EDIT**
my raw_data sheet looks like this :

```
name   id   sport    id
jane   01   football 04
mark   02   rugby    05
alonzo 03   cricket  06
            running  07
            highjump 08
            baseball 09
```

what i have after running my code is :

```
        <value id="01">
            <name>jane</name>
        </value>
        <value id="02">
            <name>mark</name>
        </value>
        <value id="03">
            <name>alonzo</name>
        </value>
        <value id="nan">
            <name>nan</name>
        </value>
        <value id="nan">
            <name>nan</name>
        </value>
        <value id="nan">
            <name>nan</name>
        </value>
```

and what i want is to get rid of the column without any values :

```
        <value id="01">
            <name>jane</name>
        </value>
        <value id="02">
            <name>mark</name>
        </value>
        <value id="03">
            <name>alonzo</name>
        </value>
```

fyi : my 'name' and 'id' column are in a table called 'nametable'
thank you

Comment: You only want the values for `Column1`? Usually you want to avoid using `.iterrows()`, is `raw_data['Column1']` what you want?

Comment: @TCMolenaar yes i only want the values in Column1. I tried changing 'for row in raw_data.iterrows():' to 'for row in raw_data['Column1'] but i'm not getting an error on the text value. : 'string indices must be integers'  because of this line : 'value.text = str(row[1]['Column1']'. So i thought of deleting 'Column1' but it still doesn't work. Yes maybe it is because i'm doing loop in a column and getting the value from the next column. I don't know how to fix it tho

Comment: Tried 'raw_data['name of my table']' but it doesn't recognize my table so i don't think that a solution

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of your input (`raw_data`) and the expected output?

Comment: @TCMolenaar i've edited my question with input, what i have and the output i want !

Comment: share the myfile.xls file. I can do this for you in a couple minutes if I can see what you are reading in exactly

Comment: @chitown88 ty but i can't see where to share the file. Is a wetransfer link ok ?

Comment: ya that would be fine. also include the part of the code where you define root, include your imports, and your part of the code that generates the output. You are only supplying part of the code here

Comment: @chitown88 here is the link with everything : <<we.tl/t-3MPWheIpAO>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ways to go about it.

1. just have a little logic in your code that skips nulls/nans.
2. Just drop those nulls rows right off the bat

**Code:**

```
from email.contentmanager import raw_data_manager
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree as et

#global raw_data

raw_data = pd.read_excel('tryout2.xlsm', sheet_name="Feuil1")

values = et.Element('values')
for row in raw_data[['Name']].dropna().iterrows():
    column_values = et.SubElement(values, 'value')

    value = et.SubElement(column_values, 'value')
    value.text = str(row[1]['Name'])

tree = et.ElementTree(values)
et.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write('new.xml', encoding="utf-8")
```

**Output:**

```
<values>
    <value>
        <value>Jane</value>
    </value>
    <value>
        <value>Mark</value>
    </value>
    <value>
        <value>Alonzo</value>
    </value>
</values>
```